# Unable to find tsclean() function after loading forecast package?

Tags: r, arima

I have a script in R for Time series forecasting. Initially when I created a time series on my univariate data and applied tsclean() function it worked. But today, when I'm trying to re-run my script again at a point where I use my tsclean() function it says:

Error in tsclean(sales_ts) : could not find function "tsclean"

I'm calling in my forecast package as well before where it says forecast package is already built in R 3.6.1.

It's weird why the function is not working today but it worked yesterday.

```
#creating time series data
sales_ts = ts(sdld_10[, c('Sales')])

#cleaning time series data 
library(forecast)
sdld_10$clean_sales = tsclean(sales_ts)
sdld_10$test<- c(sdld_10$clean_sales - sdld_10$Sales)
```

Comment: What happens if you call it explicitly like `forecast::tsclean`? **I'm calling in my forecast package as well before where it says forecast package is already built in R 3.6.1.** Maybe update R?

Comment: > library(forecast::tsclean)
Error in library(forecast::tsclean) : 'package' must be of length 1
> forecast::tsclean
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lmtest’      -- " It returns the following errors "

Comment: No, do not call `library`, just do `forecast::tsclean(dataset_name here)`.

Comment: @NelsonGon I tried this :-                                           
         forecast::tsclean(sales_ts)                                                                         
         it gave me the below error :                                                                  
         Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lmtest’

Comment: Upgrade R, uninstall forecast, reinstall with dependencies set to TRUE. Can also install lmtest first.

Comment: well it worked! Thanks a lot.